# GUI API Интерфейс input

Tags: java, api, gui, input

Я не понимаю, почему метод input не работает? Он подчеркивается красным

```
public class Prigramm extends JFrame {

    private JButton button = new JButton("Press");

    private JLabel label = new JLabel("Prigramm");

    private JTextField EBox = new JTextField(" ");

    public Prigramm(){
        super("Prigramm");
        this.setBounds(100, 100, 250, 100);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Container cont = this.getContentPane();
        cont.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 3, 2, 3));
        cont.add(label);
        cont.add(EBox);
        cont.add(button);

    }

}

class ButtonEventListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String message = " ";
                    message += input.getText();
            }


public static void main(String[] args) {

}
```

Comment: В представленном коде нет метода input. Есть переменная input, которая нигде не проинициализироана.

Comment: не объявлена, даже. Вы, когда примеры из книжки переписываете, переписывайте дословно или разбирайтесь, что там написано. В вашем случае, наверное, надо заменить `input` на `EBox`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо в коде писать

```
    class ButtonEventListener implements ActionListener {
     @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //JTextField input = (JTextField) e.getSource();
        String message = " ";
        message += EBox.getText();
        label.setText(message);
    }
}
```

Будет выводить сообщение в JLabel из JTextField.
И не забыть прикрепить слушателя к кнопке
       button.addActionListener(new ButtonEventListener);

Comment: Спасибо, помогли!

Answer (score 2):

Похоже, код класса ButtonEventListener и метод main "вылетели" из кода класса Prigramm при правке кода. Либо код приведён не полностью.

Скорее всего, в классе ButtonEventListener должен быть примерно такой код:

```
class ButtonEventListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JTextField input = (JTextField) e.getSource();
            String message = " ";
            message += input.getText();
        }
    }
```

Где **JTextField input = (JTextField) e.getSource();** - оператор получения цели возникающего события, которой является JTextField, имеющий имя "EBox" в Вашем коде.

Если Вы приведёте более полный вариант проблемного кода, возможно, всем будет легче разобраться, в чём проблема.